# JAXB: How do I marshal using field name when the return type is an interface?

Tags: java, interface, jaxb, marshalling

If I have a class (A) that contains several properties of the same type (interface B).

I've used the suggestion in http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html to use a combination of @XmlRootElement and @XmlAnyElement to get around the interface problem:

```
public interface B {...}

public class A {
...
  @XmlAnyElement
  public B getFirstB(){...}
  @XmlAnyElement
  public B getSecondB(){...}
}

// some concrete implementations of B
@XmlRootElement
public class BImpl implements B {...}

@XmlRootElement
public class AnotherBImpl implements B {...}
```

I get the following:

```
<a>
    <bImpl/>
    <anotherBImpl/>
</a>
```

But I want to distinguish between the properties. How do I get:

```
<a>
    <firstB>
        <bImpl/>
    </firstB>
    <secondB>
        <anotherBImpl/>
    </secondB>
</a>
```

As the properties are not collections, I can't use @XmlElementWrapper.

I don't really want to change the code if avoidable.

Any thoughts appreciated. Marshalling in JAXB seems to be very tricky.

Comment: This might be helpful http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: The problem isn't the interfaces per se, its this in combination with the field name.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@XmlAnyElement` with `@XmlElement(type = Object.class)`. This will distinguish individual fields.

More details on this solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41736816/2254901) to a related question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot marshal interfaces in JAXB. How would the unmarshaller know how to instantiate your interface?
Check [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/06/jaxb_and_interf.html) out, it has a really nice explanation.

Comment: I'm not interested in unmarshalling the xml.
I've already got the code serialising the concrete implementations.
But I would like to wrap them in the field name.

Answer (score 0):

I think, no magic can happen in your case. Either use a simple wrapper class (for classic JAXB) or use [`@XmlPath`](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html) (for MOXy) (acknowledgements to **Blaise Doughan**).