# JAXB marshalling purely from interfaces

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a complex hierarchy of Java interfaces that I'd like to marshal (and not necessarily unmarshal) with JAXB. These interfaces represent objects that will be returned from a JAX-RS REST API as XML, JSON, YAML, etc. (I'm using RestEasy, which can marshal JAXB-annotated types in formats other than XML.)

The problem seems to be that JAXB is fundamentally class-oriented. I've done lots of web research on the difficulties with JAXB and interfaces, the closest solutions being [MOXy JAXB - Map Interfaces to XML](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html) and [JAXB and Interface Fronted Models](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html). However, I have two main issues: a) I want to annotate/work in terms of interfaces, not the concrete classes (of which there will be multiple implementations and containing significant other state that should not be marshaled), and b) I have multiple levels of interface inheritance. Here's a sample of the interfaces, minus any JAXB annotations so far:

```
interface Uuided {
  UUID getId();
}
interface Named {
  String getName();
}
interface Component extends Uuided, Named {
  Map<String, ComponentAttribute> getAttributes();
}
interface Attribute extends Named {
  Type getType();
  Object getValue();
}
interface ComponentAttribute extends Attribute {
  Component getDeclaringComponent();
}
```

Ideally, this would generate something like:

```
<component id="xxx" name="thing">
  <attributes>
    <componentAttribute name="color">
      <type><stringType/></type>
      <value>green</value>
      <declaringComponent idref="xxx"/>
    </componentAttribute>
  </attributes>
</component>
```

Clearly, in the abstract, this leads to issues like determining the most derived annotated interface, of which there could theoretically be more than one. In my case, however, I believe the concrete classes only implement a single interface that should be marshaled. Unmarshaling is not necessary, as I have separate classes defining upsert properties.

So my question is, is this even possible to handle with JAXB, and if so, how? Even if I have to be very explicit in defining bindings, adapters, etc., I'd like to work within the JAXB framework to get the benefit of all the non-XML providers in RestEasy.

Comment: Related discussion:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/moxy-jaxb-map-interfaces-to-xml.html?showComment=1331064265196#c8558952364670027314

Comment: You will have a problem with annotating interfaces with JAXB, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is that JAXB isn't at all intended to support this and that it's foolish to try to force it. Also, JAXB-driven JSON marshaling turns out not to be ideal either.

I ended up writing my own marshaling framework, with its own set of annotations:

```
@MarshalMixin // marshal fields but not a top-level object
interface Uuided {
  @MarshalAsString // ignore properties; just call toString()
  @MarshalId // treat as identifier for @MarshalUsingIds or cyclic ref
  UUID getId();
}
@MarshalMixin
interface Named {
  @MarshalId
  String getName();
}
@MarshalObject // top-level marshaled object providing class name
interface Component extends Uuided, Named {
  @MarshalAsKeyedObjectMap(key = "name") // see description below
  Map<String, ComponentAttribute> getAttributes();
}
@MarshalObject
interface Attribute extends Named {
  Type getType();
  @MarshalDynamic // use run-time (not declared) type
  Object getValue();
}
interface ComponentAttribute extends Attribute {
  @MarshalUsingIds
  Component getDeclaringComponent();
}
```

The generated marshalers write to an abstraction layer (currently implemented for JSON and XML). This gives a lot more flexibility to make the output natural for different representations without a ton of annotations and adapters. E.g., what I'm calling keyed-object maps, where each object contains its map key. In JSON, you want a map, but in XML, you want a sequence:

```
{..., map: {'a': {'name': 'a', ...}, 'b': {'name: 'b', ...}, ...}, ...}
...<map><thing name='a'>...</thing><thing name='b'>...</thing></map>...
```

Seems like as many as 4 other people care about this too, so hopefully I can open-source it eventually. :-)

Comment: You can generalize it further to support IDL :) Why did you choose to stick to interfaces in the first place?

Comment: I didn't claim to generalize anything; I mainly decoupled marshaling from the concerns of unmarshaling. You joke, but probably what I want is indeed a good IDL; I just don't know of an IDL framework that maps well and easily between Java interfaces (not data object classes!), JSON, and XML. I need interfaces because my implementations have to deal with an object graph that is only partially resolved. They hide the fact that object references are loaded from a database on demand.

Comment: Does it looks like this option of Apache Xerces http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion ?

Comment: Why would marshalling an interface be foolish? It's totally valid requirement and it's kind of JAXB spec fail that it doesn't allow. Now I have to create a dumb class for each interface.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't open-sourced it yet. It's part of a project that's still incomplete. I'll see if I can extract the necessary pieces as time allows.

Comment: I have similar problem, cant think of any other solution. Marshalling interfaces!

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer:** use `@XmlElement(type = Object.class)` on your interface field.

Details below:

I have found 2 ways in which you could make JAXB serialize your interfaces:

1. `@XmlAnyElement`
2. `@XmlElement(type = Object.class)`

**1.@XmlAnyElement**

Simply annotate your interface type field with *`@XmlAnyElement`* and JAXB will serialize the interface from it's concrete type. Don't forget to annotate the concrete types with *`@XmlRootElement`* and to add the concrete types to the JAXBContext. Full example follows:

```
public class InterfaceSerializer {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Pojo {
        Pojo() {
            field1 = new PojoFieldImpl1();
            field2 = new PojoFieldImpl2();
            field3 = new PojoFieldImpl1();
        }

        @XmlAnyElement
        public IPojoField field1;
        @XmlAnyElement
        public IPojoField field2;
        @XmlAnyElement
        public IPojoField field3;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "field1 = " + field1 + "\nfield2 = " + field2 + "\nfield3 = " + field3;
        }
    }

    public static interface IPojoField {

    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class PojoFieldImpl1 implements IPojoField {

        PojoFieldImpl1() {
            value = "PojoFieldImpl1 value";
        }

        public String value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class PojoFieldImpl2  implements IPojoField {

        PojoFieldImpl2() {
            value = "PojoFieldImpl2 value1";
            value2 = "PojoFieldImpl2 value2";
        }

        public String value;
        public String value2;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value + " " + value2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws JAXBException {
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Pojo.class, PojoFieldImpl1.class, PojoFieldImpl2.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        marshaller.marshal(pojo, new File("interfaceSerializer.xml"));
    }
}
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pojo>
    <pojoFieldImpl1>
        <value>PojoFieldImpl1 value</value>
    </pojoFieldImpl1>
    <pojoFieldImpl2>
        <value>PojoFieldImpl2 value1</value>
        <value2>PojoFieldImpl2 value2</value2>
    </pojoFieldImpl2>
    <pojoFieldImpl1>
        <value>PojoFieldImpl1 value</value>
    </pojoFieldImpl1>
</pojo>
```

The downsides of this method:

- you can't distinguish from XML each individual field from your pojo (same implementations will be written with the same tag)
- you don't have any type information to *Unmarshall* your XML (if you would wish to do so)

These downsides are fixed in the **second solution**:

**2.@XmlElement(type = Object.class)**

I've stumbled upon this in [mikesir87's blog post](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2014/05/marshalling-interfaces-in-jax-rs/). Simply replace the *`@XmlAnyElement`* annotations from above with *`@XmlElement(type = Object.class)`*
You should have something like this in the Pojo class from above:

```
@XmlElement(type = Object.class)
public IPojoField field1;
@XmlElement(type = Object.class)
public IPojoField field2;
@XmlElement(type = Object.class)
public IPojoField field3;
```

Re-running our example, the resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pojo>
    <field1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="pojoFieldImpl1">
        <value>PojoFieldImpl1 value</value>
    </field1>
    <field2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="pojoFieldImpl2">
        <value>PojoFieldImpl2 value1</value>
        <value2>PojoFieldImpl2 value2</value2>
    </field2>
    <field3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="pojoFieldImpl1">
        <value>PojoFieldImpl1 value</value>
    </field3>
</pojo>
```

This can also be deserialized:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Pojo unmarshalledPojo = (Pojo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("interfaceSerializer.xml"));  
System.out.println(unmarshalledPojo);
```

Resulting output:

```
field1 = PojoFieldImpl1 value
field2 = PojoFieldImpl2 value1 PojoFieldImpl2 value2
field3 = PojoFieldImpl1 value
```

Probably a "*hackish*" solution, but it gets the job done.

Comment: XMLAnyElement works fine for services that operate directly on the XML stream, as you (yourself) don't need to deserialize the outputs with bindings.